# Java: how to serialize a 3rd party library produced Java Object?

Tags: java, serialization

So I am using a proprietary java library in a project which I don't have access to source code.

It throws a Message object, and obviously I can't implement Serializable. It's generated throughout runtime.

what are my options? Is there a way to serialize the Message object into a byte array and back into the object?

UPDATE: I was able to serialize the object to JSON (http://code.google.com/p/json-io/) but couldn't convert it back to an object as it returns null. So I am trying to convert it to byte array using the code below. Still not working.

```
public byte[] toByteArray (Object obj)
{
  byte[] bytes = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.flush(); 
    oos.close(); 
    bos.close();
    bytes = bos.toByteArray ();
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  return bytes;
}

public Object toObject (byte[] bytes)
{
  Object obj = null;
  try {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (bis);
    obj = ois.readObject();
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the object already implements Serializable? If you don't know, you might just try it to see if it works.

Comment: it doesn't implement Serializable already.

Comment: do you mean something like `public MyMessage extends 3rd.party.Message implements Serializable{}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) is one way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a wrapper that is serializable and stores everything you need to recreate the Message object.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just can't use the `java.lang.Serializable` mechanism.

Choose any format: XML, JSON, [protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), or something else that might work for you.

Now you're responsible for both ends of the conversation: serialization and deserialization.

Comment: its protocol buffer, not prototype buffer.

Comment: Thank you, I was going too fast.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is a Java bean, you can use `java.beans.XMLEncoder` and `java.beans.XMLDecoder` for serialization.